# Solaris 10 time command to find execution time and save in a text file

Tags: solaris, execution-time

H,

There is Solaris command "time" to find execution time of command ... e.g.

time command

I need to execute this "time command" command and save output in a file.

I can find -o flag in Linux (e.g.  /usr/bin/time -o output.txt COMMAND) but this is not working in Solaris 10.

I would be thankful if some expert guide me to implement it in Solaris.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect the output of `time` command to file:

```
time command >>output.txt 2>&1
```

the construction `2>&1` make `STDERR` also to go in the same file

And this work (with very high probability) on **ANY Unix and Linux**